# The sum of Dirichlet's kernel

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Assume $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$
I define:
$$S_N = \sum \limits_{k = -N}^{k=N} c_ke^{2 \pi ikx},$$
where $c_k = \int \limits_{0}^{1} f(x)e^{2 \pi ikx} \mbox{d}x$.
I managed to show that:
$$S_N = \int \limits_{0}^{1} f(x-t)D_N(t) \mbox{d}t.$$ 
Where $D_N(t) = \sum \limits_{k=N}^Ne^{2 \pi ikx}$ (Dirichlet's kernel).
Now I would like to show that:
$$D_N(t) = \frac{\sin \big(\pi(2N + 1)t \big)}{\sin(\pi t)}$$
I did show that:
$$D_n(t) = 1 + 2\sum \limits_{k = 1}^N \cos(2 \pi kt)$$
I don't know where to go from here however. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$D_N(t) = \sum_{k=-N}^Ne^{2\pi i k t}
=e^{-2\pi i N t}\sum_{k=0}^{2N}e^{2\pi i k t}=e^{-2\pi i N t}\frac{e^{2\pi i (2N+1) t}-1}{e^{2\pi i t}-1}=\frac{\sin \big(\pi(2N + 1)t \big)}{\sin(\pi t)}.$$

Comment: That was a very smart solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @Hendrra you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ it is obvious that $D_N(x)=2N+1$. For $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$: Let $z=e^{2\pi ix}$ Factorize with $z^{-N}$. It is $D_N(x)=z^{-N}\cdot\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2N}z^k=z^{-N}\cdot\frac{z^{2N+1}-1}{z-1}}$. Can you pick it up from this point?